# How to get R installation date?

Tags: r, date, installation

I have a symple question: I need to know when R was installed on a cluster (linux-based). How could I get this information?

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using windows, you can check it in settings --> apps

Comment: Sorry, I did not include, the os is linux. I will edit.